# Convert SQL query to C#? for Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using Stored Procedure in SQL Server for Next Number. I need to input next number using Stored Procedure from SQL Server.

```
execute  get_next_no @no_type_name = 'customer id', @return_value = 'N';
```

That is working in SQL Server, but i don't know to to use this query in ASP.NET API.

There are two Parameter for `get_next_no`, so I don't know how to use that parameter using different Table.

[image: That is my Table for using Parameter]

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_next_no] (
        @no_type_name                   varchar(30),
        @return_value                   char(1)                 
      = NULL)
      as
      begin
       declare @next_no                int
       declare @no_type_code           char(6)
       select  @next_no = next_no,
               @no_type_code = no_type_code
        from    posit_db..sys_nos (HOLDLOCK)
        where   upper(no_type_name) = upper(@no_type_name)
        if (@next_no = NULL) or (@next_no < 0)
        begin
                select  @next_no = -1
        end
        if (@next_no = 0)
        begin
              select  @next_no = 1
        end
        update  posit_db..sys_nos
        set     next_no = @next_no + 1
        where   no_type_code = @no_type_code
        if (@return_value = 'y')
        begin
                return @next_no
        end
        select @next_no
        end
```

That is the stored procedure code.

Please help me how to convert SQL query to ASP.NET API.

Comment: Just a curious note, in all my years of programming, all the places i have worked for, and all the projects i have been involved in, i have never had to create a db next number SP or logic like this. Usually its a sign of a bad design decision by someone who has OCD for ordered and sequential numbers with no relationship to the real world problem it was trying to solve,  not to mention a nightmare for scalable systems. Anyway... that titbit aside, you need to attempt something. This question is essentially, a *Gimme Codez* question

Comment: Are you trying to “convert” this SQL to C# or are you trying to “use” the existing stored procedure from a C# program because those are two very different things.

Comment: @MichaelRandall well said wish I could upvote more.

Comment: I try to use that Stored Procedure using C#.

Comment: Basically, you want to do MySQL / SQL queries in C#?